# How to replace letters (ex. ABC) in all instances in a sentence in a string without the replace() function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

This is what I have so far but in order to replace a, b and c I would like to know how I can incorporate replacing all 3 letters in all occurrences in the sentence. I also am not allowed to use replace() function.

```
def changeLetters(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "a": #I would like to replace a,b and c
            word.replace(letter,"!") #replace the replace() function
    return word
```

**User input example:**

```
Amy buys carrots and apples
```

**User output example:**

```
!my 3uys 8!rrots !nd !pples
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You say you want to replace `a`, `b` and `c`, but your code (unsuccessfully) attempts to replace every letter *but* `a`. Can you give an example output to go with the example input?

Comment: You could "replace" the letter by just overwriting it. Remember you can index strings i.e. if `a = "cat"` then `a[0]` would be `c` and `a[1]` would be `a` etc. You could use this by doing `a[1] = "*"` which would make `c*t`.

Comment: Please, post your desired result.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Yes but what if the word is an input from the user?

Comment: My solution below would work in that case, if the input was assigned to the variable that the function is performed on.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = 'Amy buys carrots and apples'
result = ''.join(['!' if x == 'a' else '3' if x == 'b' else '8' if x == 'c' else x for x in word.lower()])
result
'!my 3uys 8!rrots !nd !pples'
```

Comment: Thank you! However what if want to replace b with 3 and c with 8 instead of ! replacing all of a,b and c

Comment: `''.join(['3' if x == 'b' else '8' if x == 'c' else x for x in word])`

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
first_word = "Amy buys carrots and apples"
def changeLetters(word):
    word_list = [] #creates a list to be filled by letters
    for letter in word: # fills the list with letters from string
        if letter == "a" or letter == "b" or letter == "c": #searches for a b or c
            letter = "!" #replaces a b or c with !
        word_list.append(letter) # appends the current letter to the list
    new_word = "".join(word_list) #joins the letters in the list into a string
    return new_word # returns the value of the new word
print(changeLetters(first_word))
```

You can modify or insert "if" statements to replace the capital "A" or assign different replacement characters to letters as needed.